# How to get the network requests from browser using selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I am using DotNet Core for my selenium code.
I want to validate the status code from my browser using selenium.
Using the below code I am able to get the network request details but I am not able to parse the details

```
String script = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
var networkdata = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driverHelper.Driver).ExecuteScript(script).ToString();
```

The output I get through the above code is in object type
[Output from debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdNaq.jpg)

I want to get the request name and requeststatus value

**Is there are way to get the request details from browser using selenium C#?**

With the below code I am able to get the details from browser console tab

```
List<LogEntry> entries = _driverHelper.Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).ToList();
```

But not sure how to get details from network tab

I tried with IDevTools also but that is not working fine with me.

Answer (score 4):

Using `IDevTools` is straightforward.

```
using var driver = new ChromeDriver();

IDevTools devTools = driver;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
await session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();
session.DevToolsEventReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.EventName == EventName.RequestWillBeSent)
    {
        // get data from `e.EventData`
    }
};

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(TargetUrl);
```

```
public static class EventName
{
    public const string RequestWillBeSentExtraInfo = "requestWillBeSentExtraInfo";
    public const string RequestWillBeSent = "requestWillBeSentExtraInfo";
    public const string ResponseReceivedExtraInfo = "responseReceivedExtraInfo";
    public const string ResponseReceived = "responseReceived";
    public const string AttachedToTarget = "attachedToTarget";
    public const string DetachedFromTarget = "detachedFromTarget";    
}
```